# Bentley-Ottmann for a mixture of segment types

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

Is it possible to use the Bentley-Ottmann algorithm with a mixture of allowed segment types, say, line segments and arcs?

The same question could be asked for Balaban's algorithm but it's gonna be for an other time.

[image: Excerpt from original study]

http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a058768.pdf

Comment: Does an intersection point between any two segments depend on any other segment? Is there more than one intersection?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to find all intersections. I know that their own study remarked that you could use the algorithm for arcs (and even other types of 'segments') but I'm not sure if you can mix them together all at once.

Comment: I added an excerpt to clarify what types of segments I am talking about (it's from the original study). From what I can tell it should be perfectly fine to mix up segment types in the input of the algorithm, but maybe someone knows better.